# SVG XSS & WP firewall

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, xss

how is it with SVG and XSS? I know that SVG has xml structure and can contain harmful scripts. From that knowledge we do not allow SVG upload on our WP site but.

From our graphics we received new icons for our web in SVG. They are clear and do not contain any harmful scripts. We placed them on web using div with style background-image.

Is that any vulnerable to XSS or not and if so then why? Should we rather use @2x and @3x images instead of SVG? The thing is in img and css style the SVG should not execute any scripts. In object, iframe Yes?

Also we used wordfence and now thinking about NinjaFirewall. Is it better?

Comment: when used as a background image scripting is disabled in SVG

Comment: So when we used the SVG file as background image i should not care about it and it is all safe? :-)